# Eclipse: Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-2, m2eclipse, m2e

I have a Maven project I'm trying to build/run in Eclipse but I'm getting the error below. How do I do what the error suggests and add the -e or X switches to try to troubleshoot this?

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.bsc.maven:maven-processor-plugin:2.0.5:process (process) on project glw-crm: Error executing: NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I'm using Eclipse Indigo (64 bit) and m2e 1.0.1

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You should check `Debug Output` in m2e configuration:

Window -> Preferences -> Maven -> Debug Output

Answer (score 2):

As of IntelliJ 2019.2.2

File -> Settings (Ctrl + Alt+ S) -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Maven -> Output Level: Debug